# Fragment wont show in activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am very new to android development. I went through several  tutorials on fragments but for some reason i cant seem to add a fragment from my main view. I'm not trying to do anything painfully complicated. All I want is to create my fragments and add them to my main activity. That's it. But every time I run my application all I get is a blank screen. I debug it and it is going to the fragment. This leads me to believe that the issue may be in the xml laout file (maybe).

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.android.myCompany.nameOfApp;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Begin the transaction
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.foo_frame_layout, new FooFragment());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Here is my Fragment.cs

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FooFragment extends Fragment {

    public FooFragment () {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setText(R.string.hello_blank_fragment);
        return textView;
    }
}
```

Here is my layout activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background_portrait">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/copyright_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my fragment_foo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/copyright_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FooFragment">
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="102dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <ImageView
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my set up? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you return `TextView` instead of your **fragment layout xml** in your fragment class?

Comment: @JeelVankhede I was following a tutorial. I was going to change things afterwards. Is that the issue?

Comment: You're not actually using the `fragment_foo` layout, atm. Assuming this is just for testing, then the `TextView` is fine for now, though. Given that, is it possible that the `TextView`'s text color is just blending in with the background color? You might try setting a contrasting text color, or a background color on the `TextView`, or some other attribute to make it stand out. Your code looks OK, at first glance.

Comment: @MikeM. I thought about that but I have an image that gives contrast to any text that may be drawn on the screen.

Comment: @user2529011 yes that's the issue !

Comment: OK, what happens if instead you `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foo, container, false);` from `onCreateView()`? Same thing?

Comment: @MikeM. yeah I saw it pop up on the top left (0,0). At that point I was happy to see I was heading in the right direction. But thank you and all for your quick response.

Comment: An, cool, you saw that. I accidentally deleted my comment, trying to edit it. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in your fragment class...

```
public static FooFragment newInstance()
{
    return new FooFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    // work with your ui code here.
    return view;
}
```

And call this method in your activity...

```
// Begin the transaction
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.foo_frame_layout, FooFragment.newInstance());
ft.commit();
```

Comment: You are awesome sir. just what i needed. I was so tangled up and everyone uses fragment so differently. Now I need to come up with some Fragment Manager so I can call whatever Fragment I need to show in my main activity

Answer (score 2):

Change with this in your fragment class :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foo, container, false); // This line will inflate your fragment_foo layout and return it's rootview for fragment inflation
}
```

and then find your fragment views in `onViewCreated` method of fragment.